# Save a copy of Excel file to SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the `SaveCopyAs`, rather than the `SaveAs` function, to keep the original file open.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim strName As String

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strName = wsA.Range("B5").Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=XXXXXX
 If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Enabled = False
End If
Worksheets("Sheet1").CommandButton6.Visible = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=XXXXXX
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="http://XXXXsharepoint pathXXX" & "/" & 
strName & ".xlsm"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=XXXXXX
    Worksheets("Sheet1").CommandButton6.Visible = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=XXXXXX

End Sub
```

The above code is giving me a 1004 error.

Comment: You need to tell us which line gives the error

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your response. the error is triggered at "ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="http://XXXXsharepoint pathXXX" & "/" & 
strName & ".xlsm" ", the error that i am getting is "application-defined or object-defined error. if i use SaveAs it works fine.

Comment: Do you mean `ThisWorkbook` or `wbA`?  Is your code running in the Active workbook?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e6a3a94-e528-451b-866d-2b552c4e53e8/xl-vba-savecopyas-into-sharepoint-not-working-but-save-as-is-fine?forum=exceldev  describes the issue and also has one or two workarounds

Comment: Yes the code is running in the active workbook. thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the info.